# COMException (0x80005000): Unknown error - UserPrincipal.set_GivenName(String value)

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory

I have the following code which is called inside of an ASP.NET application:

```
public DomainUserInfo GetDomainUserInfoByName(string domain, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    string[] domainArray = domain.Split(',');
    foreach (string d in domainArray)
    {
        var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, d);
        var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext) {GivenName = firstName, Surname = lastName};
        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
        {
            userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) searcher.FindOne();
        }

        if (userPrincipal != null)
        {

            var domainUserInfo = new DomainUserInfo
            {
                FirstName = userPrincipal.GivenName,
                LastName = userPrincipal.Surname,
                Email = userPrincipal.EmailAddress,
                LanID = userPrincipal.SamAccountName,
                Extension = userPrincipal.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
                DomainName = d,
                NTAccountName = userPrincipal.Sid.Translate(typeof (NTAccount)).ToString()
            };

            return domainUserInfo;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works when deployed on some servers but not on others, where it throws the exception:

```
[COMException (0x80005000): Unknown error (0x80005000)]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +386081
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +36
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +31
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +21
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) +49
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) +135
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer() +288
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit() +37
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize() +118
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ContextForType(Type t) +34
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetStoreCtxToUse() +37
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.set_GivenName(String value) +17
   Mfc.Inv.RM.Framework.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryManager.GetDomainUserInfoByName(String domain, String firstName, String lastName) +167
```

It looks like this is occurring on the line:

```
var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext) {GivenName = firstName, Surname = lastName};
```

when trying to set the `GivenName` property of the `UserPrincipal` object.

I'm totally stuck as to what could be causing this, especially since it works on some servers and not others. I already tried writing a console application that calls the same code it works on all of the servers, so I am guessing it has to be something to do with IIS.

Comment: are you familiar with PrincipalCOntext..? if so why do you need to do the following `var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext) {GivenName = firstName, Surname = lastName};` you should be able to get at all the necessary information just using PrincipalContext also the reason it may not work on other servers is because the other servers may not be in the same Domain or AD Tree. get with your Admin as well

Comment: @DJKRAZE I did not write the code. Also, PrincipalContext does not have properties for GivenName or Surname, or EmailAddress (which we use to search in a different method)

Comment: funny.. because I am looking at some code right now that I can see that.. let me clarify you do not need to use the new UserPrincipal I will show you what I am doing and what I mean and it works very well..

Comment: On PrincipalContext class? All I see is Name and UserName

Comment: @DJKRAZE Also, just verified all the servers are members of the same (correct) domain.

Comment: look at my working example as soon as you you Create new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Doommain, yourdomainname, null, null) it will know what your username is .. just try it it's simple easy readable code. I am passing domainName from the .config file where I store it by the way.

Comment: I don't want to use the current users identity, I need to search for accounts based on string input from UI

Comment: are you saying you would allow another user to search for someone based on their firstname lastname..? can you clarify..if so then you can use a similar construct as well

Answer (score 0):

here is what I am doing and if you were to hover over `userFind` or do a QuickWatch on it you will see the following information. also notice the IdentityType.SamAccountName that I am passing

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, null, null);
var userFind = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
```